# Selection Sort Implementation

Tags: c#, .net

Is this a proper [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)?
Any code issues?

```
public static void SelectionSort(ref int[] a)
{
    int n = a.Length;
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
    {
        int iMin = j;
        for (int i = j + 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[iMin])
            {
                iMin = i;
            }
        }
        if (iMin != j)
        {
            int temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[iMin];
            a[iMin] = temp;
        }
    }
}

//test 
int[] ar = new int[] { 90, 90, 71, 82, 93, 75, 81, 54, 36, 102, 99, 34, -56, 103, 78, 796, 52, -56, 5, 215 };
SelectionSort(ref ar);
foreach (int i in ar)
    Debug.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Can't imagine what is wrong with this question

Comment: Could be because from your question it appears you haven't verified whether it works as intended.

Comment: @Mast I have tested

Comment: What purpose of the `ref` keyword for the `a` parameter? Since you just set values of an array it is useless. As for downvote I think it is because of the task itself. Selection sort is one of the first algorithms when people start to learn programming. You doesn't look like a beginner so it is really strange to see this post from you :) Of course there are tons of code examples of this sort on all programming languages including C#.

Comment: @Maxim Another user posted a really bad home grown sort so I wanted an example of go to WIKI and implement.

Comment: @Maxim You are right what was I thinking with ref?

Comment: You won't believe it but I actually upvoted your question ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The parameter does not need to be a `ref`, since there is no assignment to the variable `a` in the `SelectionSort` method.
- There are too few tests.
- The current test data looks entirely random, as if you had no idea what the interesting cases were.
- The tests should at least cover some interesting edge cases, like:

  - An empty array
  - An array with only 1 element
  - An array with 2 elements
  - An array with 10 equal elements
  - An array that is sorted ascendingly
  - An array that is sorted descendingly
  - An array that is random
  - An array containing `int.MinValue`, 0, `int.MaxValue`
  - An array of 5 elements, in which every permutation is tested whether it sorts to the same results
- The test code should be presented in the question as real test methods, not just a code snippet.

Comment: Correct it does not need ref.   Someone commented I did not test so I added that.  I did test other cases.

Answer (score 2):

As it's already been said, using `ref` as a parameter does not have any advantages here **but**... it can be used as the new **C# 7** feature with return values and local variables which I find allows us to greatly improve the readability of the algorithm. By using it this way we can now return a reference to an array item and also use `ref` local variables that we can overwrite. We no longer have to work with indexes everywhere. Setting the variables will set array items.

```
public static void SelectionSort(int[] collection)
{
    var n = collection.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        ref var currentValue = ref collection[i];
        ref var minValue = ref FindMinValue(collection, i);
        if (minValue != currentValue)
        {
            var temp = currentValue;
            currentValue = minValue;
            minValue = temp;
        }
    }
}

private static ref int FindMinValue(int[] collection, int offset)
{
    var iMin = offset;
    for (var i = offset + 1; i < collection.Length; i++)
    {
        if (collection[i] < collection[iMin])
        {
            iMin = i;
        }
    }
    return ref collection[iMin];
}
```